# Assigning values to columns based on groups in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a data set that looks approximately like this:

```
data_set = pd.DataFrame([
    {'img_type': 'bias', 'CCD-TEMP': -10, 'explen': 0, 'mean': 1023.4234},
    {'img_type': 'bias', 'CCD-TEMP': -10, 'explen': 0, 'mean': 1024.4334},
    {'img_type': 'bias', 'CCD-TEMP': -15, 'explen': 0, 'mean': 1022.2344},
    {'img_type': 'bias', 'CCD-TEMP': -15, 'explen': 0, 'mean': 1021.1031},
    {'img_type': 'dark', 'CCD-TEMP': -10, 'explen': 30, 'mean': 1025.9959},
    {'img_type': 'dark', 'CCD-TEMP': -10, 'explen': 30, 'mean': 1023.3434},
    {'img_type': 'dark', 'CCD-TEMP': -10, 'explen': 60, 'mean': 1020.1234},
    {'img_type': 'dark', 'CCD-TEMP': -10, 'explen': 60, 'mean': 1022.4234},
    {'img_type': 'dark', 'CCD-TEMP': -15, 'explen': 30, 'mean': 1025.9959},
    {'img_type': 'dark', 'CCD-TEMP': -15, 'explen': 30, 'mean': 1023.3434},
    {'img_type': 'dark', 'CCD-TEMP': -15, 'explen': 60, 'mean': 1020.1234},
    {'img_type': 'dark', 'CCD-TEMP': -15, 'explen': 60, 'mean': 1022.4234},
    ])
```

What I am trying to do is isolate the img_type='bias' rows, group them by CCD-TEMP, and calculate the mean() of 'mean' for each group. This seems to do that trick:

```
>>> data_set[data_set['img_type'].isin(['bias'])].groupby('CCD-TEMP')['mean'].mean()
... 
CCD-TEMP
-15    1021.66875
-10    1023.92840
Name: mean, dtype: float64
```

What I need to do now is apply those values to a new column called 'Offset' to a group of all rows based on CCD-TEMP. I've tried a few things so far, the last attempt looking as follows:

```
>>> data_set['Offset'] = data_set[data_set['img_type'].isin(['bias'])].groupby('CCD-TEMP')['mean'].mean()
>>> data_set
    CCD-TEMP  explen img_type       mean  Offset
0        -10       0     bias  1023.4234     NaN
1        -10       0     bias  1024.4334     NaN
2        -15       0     bias  1022.2344     NaN
3        -15       0     bias  1021.1031     NaN
4        -10      30     dark  1025.9959     NaN
5        -10      30     dark  1023.3434     NaN
6        -10      60     dark  1020.1234     NaN
7        -10      60     dark  1022.4234     NaN
8        -15      30     dark  1025.9959     NaN
9        -15      30     dark  1023.3434     NaN
10       -15      60     dark  1020.1234     NaN
11       -15      60     dark  1022.4234     NaN
```

Obviously NaN is not what I'm after.

What is the best way to approach something like this with pandas? I'm going to need to do similar with groups of ('CCD-TEMP', 'explen') once I get passed this hurdle. Any advice to that end is welcome as well.

Comment: How working my solution?

Comment: It works. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think need if want assign to `bias` rows [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with `mean`:

```
data_set['Offset'] = data_set[data_set['img_type'].isin(['bias'])].groupby('CCD-TEMP')['mean'].transform('mean')
print (data_set)
    CCD-TEMP  explen img_type       mean      Offset
0        -10       0     bias  1023.4234  1023.92840
1        -10       0     bias  1024.4334  1023.92840
2        -15       0     bias  1022.2344  1021.66875
3        -15       0     bias  1021.1031  1021.66875
4        -10      30     dark  1025.9959         NaN
5        -10      30     dark  1023.3434         NaN
6        -10      60     dark  1020.1234         NaN
7        -10      60     dark  1022.4234         NaN
8        -15      30     dark  1025.9959         NaN
9        -15      30     dark  1023.3434         NaN
10       -15      60     dark  1020.1234         NaN
11       -15      60     dark  1022.4234         NaN
```

Or if need [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) output of `mean` by column `CCD-TEMP`:

```
s = data_set[data_set['img_type'].isin(['bias'])].groupby('CCD-TEMP')['mean'].mean()
print (s)
CCD-TEMP
-15    1021.66875
-10    1023.92840
Name: mean, dtype: float64

data_set['Offset'] = data_set['CCD-TEMP'].map(s)
print (data_set)
    CCD-TEMP  explen img_type       mean      Offset
0        -10       0     bias  1023.4234  1023.92840
1        -10       0     bias  1024.4334  1023.92840
2        -15       0     bias  1022.2344  1021.66875
3        -15       0     bias  1021.1031  1021.66875
4        -10      30     dark  1025.9959  1023.92840
5        -10      30     dark  1023.3434  1023.92840
6        -10      60     dark  1020.1234  1023.92840
7        -10      60     dark  1022.4234  1023.92840
8        -15      30     dark  1025.9959  1021.66875
9        -15      30     dark  1023.3434  1021.66875
10       -15      60     dark  1020.1234  1021.66875
11       -15      60     dark  1022.4234  1021.66875
```

Comment: .map() seems to be the key. Thanks!